# From single thread to multi threading image processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, multiprocessing, c++17

I'm transforming my code from a single thread to multi threading process, then I get to that part of the code where I'm struggling:

where `src`, `imJ` and `IllumTrans` are just images of size `1288*728` and `A` is constant value

```
for(auto j=0;j<rows;j++)
  for(auto i=0;i<cols;i++)
     imJ.at<float>(j,i)= A+((src.at<uchar>(j,i)-A)/std::max(IllumTrans.at<float>(j,i), 0.1f));
```

I'm processing RGB images and what I was doing is running the same code (the above double for loop) for each channel which I thought could be nice if I run it in multi threading process.

I started the multi threading version like so

```
cv::Mat imJ=cv::Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_32FC3);
cv::MatConstIterator<cv::Vec3b> it_src = src.begin();
cv::MatConstIterator<cv::Vec3f> it_IllumTrans = IllumTrans.begin();
imJ.forEach<cv::Vec3f>
(
  [A, &IllumTrans, rows, cols](cv::Vec3f &pixel, const int* po) -> void
  {
    pixel[0]= A+(((*it_src)[0]-A[0])/std::max((*it_IllumTrans)[0], 0.1f));
    pixel[1]= A+(((*it_src)[0]-A[1])/std::max((*it_IllumTrans)[1], 0.1f));
    pixel[2]= A+(((*it_src)[0]-A[2])/std::max((*it_IllumTrans)[2], 0.1f));
    it_src++;
    it_IllumTrans++;
  }
);
```

But I didn't succeed it, it said `'MatIterator’ is not a member of ‘cv’`.

What do you think about my new version, is it the right way to do it?

**Compilation information:**

```
g++ -std=c++1z -Wall -Weffc++ -Ofast -march=native test4.cpp -o test4 -fopenmp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: Since `forEach` runs the function (lambda in your case) on multiple threads in parallel (and one call per pixel), what's to guarantee that the increments of the two iterators are actually in order? (I'd say nothing)

Comment: BTW, try to make the code you post with your questions a [mcve], so that we can just copy it and try to compile locally without having to add anything or guess things. Right now, among other things, it's not evident what the datatype of `A` is.

Comment: I detect a distinct lack of synchronization.

Comment: It's almost impossible to optimise multithreading without knowing the bigger picture. If you only show a small part of your application, you end up micro-optimising one aspect when actually there are much bigger gains to be made restructuring parts we cannot see. For example, if you are processing thousands of images, it may be better to assign one image to a thread so the cache stays hot rather than splitting each image across multiple threads and paying big penalties for synchronisation. Just my 2 pence (UK).

Comment: @MarkSetchell As I'm working in a big project, I can't share all my code. I only need help where I think I'm not good at or I can't do it. I'm processing one image at once because it is an real time application. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see with your implementation using `cv::Mat::forEach` is that the order in which the shared iterators `it_src` and `it_IllumTrans` will be non-deterministic once the lambda is ran on more than one thread in parallel. You will end up with unpredictably jumbled mess.

---

One way to deal with is would be to use the position parameter of the function called by [`cv::Mat::forEach`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d), and use this to get pointers (iterators would be an overkill here) to the correct locations in the two input `Mat`s.

```
cv::Mat3f variant_1(cv::Mat3b const& source
    , cv::Mat3f const& illum_trans
    , cv::Vec3f const& offset)
{
    CV_Assert(!source.empty());
    CV_Assert(!illum_trans.empty());
    CV_Assert(source.size() == illum_trans.size());

    cv::Mat3f result(source.size());

    result.forEach([&source, &illum_trans, &offset](cv::Vec3f &pixel, const int p[]) {
        cv::Vec3b const* it_src(source.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(p[0], p[1]));
        cv::Vec3f const* it_trans(illum_trans.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(p[0], p[1]));

        for (int32_t ch(0); ch < 3; ++ch) {
            pixel[ch] = offset[ch]
                + (((*it_src)[ch] - offset[ch])
                    / std::max((*it_trans)[ch], 0.1f));
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

---

The second approach would be to use [`parallel_for_`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html), and partition the image among the threads by rows. This means that we would only have to get the pointers once per row (we need to consider that the input images may not be continuous), and just increment them the rest of the time.

```
class ParallelVariant2
    : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    ParallelVariant2(cv::Mat3b const& source
        , cv::Mat3f& destination
        , cv::Mat3f const& illum_trans
        , cv::Vec3f const& offset)
        : source_(source)
        , destination_(destination)
        , illum_trans_(illum_trans)
        , offset_(offset)
    {
        CV_Assert(!source.empty());
        CV_Assert(!illum_trans.empty());
        CV_Assert(source.size() == illum_trans.size());

        destination_.create(source.size());
    }

    virtual void operator()(const cv::Range& range) const
    {
        for (int32_t row(range.start); row < range.end; ++row) {
            cv::Vec3b const* it_src(source_.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(row));
            cv::Vec3f* it_dst(destination_.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(row));
            cv::Vec3f const* it_trans(illum_trans_.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(row));

            for (int32_t col(0); col < source_.cols; ++col) {
                for (int32_t ch(0); ch < 3; ++ch) {
                    (*it_dst)[ch] = offset_[ch]
                        + (((*it_src)[ch] - offset_[ch])
                            / std::max((*it_trans)[ch], 0.1f));
                }
                ++it_src; ++it_dst; ++it_trans;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    cv::Mat3b const& source_;
    cv::Mat3f& destination_;
    cv::Mat3f const& illum_trans_;
    cv::Vec3f const& offset_;
};

cv::Mat3f variant_2(cv::Mat3b const& source
    , cv::Mat3f const& illum_trans
    , cv::Vec3f const& offset)
{
    cv::Mat3f result;
    ParallelVariant2 impl(source, result, illum_trans, offset);
    cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, source.rows), impl);
    return result;
}
```

---

A short test program.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

// paste implementations here

int main()
{
    cv::Mat3b source(1024, 1024);
    cv::randu(source, 0, 256);

    cv::Mat3f illum_trans(1024, 1024);
    cv::randu(illum_trans, 0, 1.0);

    cv::Vec3f offset(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f);

    cv::Mat3f result_1 = variant_1(source, illum_trans, offset);
    cv::Mat3f result_2 = variant_2(source, illum_trans, offset);

    std::cout << std::equal(result_1.begin(), result_1.end(), result_2.begin()) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got that issue with synchronization (y) 
Thanks, your sample code helped me to solve my issues